# How to pause a Httpurlconnection in android on button click

Tags: java, android, http-post, httpurlconnection

I am entirely new to android development and I have been sending a large file through httpurlconnection in android.
The code i used for uploading files through httpurlconnection is

```java
 try {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile));

    URL url = new URL(urlServer);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    // Allow Inputs & Outputs
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024)

    // Enable POST method
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

    outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

    // TOKENID
    String token = "anyvalye";
    outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Token\"" + lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8" + lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Length: " + token.length() + lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes(token + lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

    String connstr = null;
    connstr = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"UploadFile\";filename=\""
            + pathToOurFile + "\"" + lineEnd;

    outputStream.writeBytes(connstr);
    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    TotalFileSize=bufferSize;

    System.out.println("Initial Max Size" + bytesAvailable + "");
    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    // Read file
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    try {
        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            try {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                response = "outofmemoryerror";
                return response;
            }
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        response = "error";
        return response;
    }
    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

    // Responses from the server (code and message)
    int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
    System.out.println("Server Response Code " + " " + serverResponseCode);
    System.out.println("Server Response Message "+ serverResponseMessage);

    if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
        response = "true";
    } else {
        response = "false";
    }

    fileInputStream.close();
    outputStream.flush();

    connection.getInputStream();
    //for android InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
    java.io.InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();

    int ch;
    StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
    while((ch = is.read()) != -1 ) {
        b.append((char)ch);
    }

    String responseString = b.toString();
    System.out.println("response string is" + responseString); //Here is the actual output

    outputStream.close();
    outputStream = null;

} catch (Exception ex) {
    // Exception handling
    response = "error";
    System.out.println("Send file Exception" + ex.getMessage() + "");
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
return response;
```

I came to know that during downloading files, we can pause and resume the download and there are a lot of codes available. I tried that codes and also got the solution.

But can i pause and resume the upload process in Httpurlconnection. Forgive me if my question is silly because i am newly learning this concepts. Can anyone help me here for pausing and resuming upload since there are no codes available upto my knowledge.

After debugging, i am getting the response for size of file upload here at this piece of code,

```java
bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
try {
    while (bytesRead > 0) {
        try {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "outofmemoryerror";
            return response;
        }
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    response = "error";
    return response;
}
```

Hoping to get some help to update myself.

Comment: Stream pause/resume is a feature given by the ability of the two clients to handle the `Range` header field. If the sender (make it the server or the client) is able to handle sending chunks of content and the receiver is able to handle the reconstruction, it should work quite similar. [Here an expanation on how it works](https://superuser.com/questions/641950/how-do-pause-able-downloads-work). You will have to adapt the server too, to handle partial uploads, i don't think it can do by itself as witht he downloads.

Comment: @bracco23 is urlconnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024) enough to send the file as chunk from the client side to the server?

Comment: It will probably be part of the code, but you first have to be sure your server is capable of handling a file sent in chunks. Also you will have to handle to keep the count of the chunk sent and the ones to send to be able to resume.

Answer (score 0):

````
```
 bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            try {
                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    try {
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        response = "outofmemoryerror";
                        return response;
                    }
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                response = "error";
                return response;
}
        }
    ```
````